# Can iPhoto create a board book?

Tags: photos.app

I'm looking to make a board book for my 2 year old son.  I don't see any obvious settings in iPhoto that lets me choose the paper thickness.  It is pretty important to me because my son loves to tear "normal" books apart and so far his board books have held up.

Answer (score 1):

iPhoto doesn't provide this functionality.
There are two things you could do at this point:

- Submit feedback to Apple on iPhoto [here](http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphoto.html). Please note that it might take a while for them to implement your feature, and they don't respond to comments.
- Use an alternative 'board book maker'. After a quick web search, I found [this](http://www.pintsizeproductions.com/Design-a-board-book.html) website (pintsizeproductions.com). I'm sure you'll be able to find some more with a similar search.